# Disable return key in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to disable the return key found when typing in a `UITextView`. I want the text to have no page indents like found in a `UITextField`. This is the code I have so far:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText
{
if ([aTextView.text isEqualToString:@"\r\n"]) {
    return NO;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to use like this..

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account all possible line ending characters, or the fact that a user may paste a chunk of text in one go into the text field (so not equal to "\n" but containing it) - Grzegorz's solution is much more robust.

Comment: Just to clarify, I refer to the UITextview answer rather than the UITextField answers.

Answer (score 20):

Another solution without magic hardcoded strings will be:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:    (NSString *)text {
    if( [text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound ) {
        return YES;
    }     

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: +1, I like the idea of not using magic strings, which could change (they wont, but you catch my drift); It also reads easier.

Answer (score 13):

In Swift 3+ add:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    guard text.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines) == nil else {
        // textView.resignFirstResponder() // uncomment this to close the keyboard when return key is pressed
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Don't forget to add `textView`'s delegate in order for this to be called

Answer (score -1):

I know this is late reply but this code is perfect working for me. 
This will disable return key initially until type any character.

```
textfield.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
```

By Interface Builder set this property,
[image]

Comment: The answer is about a textView, not a textField.

Answer (score -4):

why dont you change `UITextView` return key type like this?

[image]