# Disable Return key in keyboard for TextView

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard, textview, return

I need to disable the Return key on the keyboard for a specific controller, when the user is writing in a TextView but I can't find any working solutions on the web (they seems to work for the TextField but not for the TextView).
How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable return key in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719367/disable-return-key-in-uitextview)

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of above ticket.

Comment: It’s not a duplicate. That solution is in OBJ C and doesn’t work for me in Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return text != "\n"
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked fine! :D